# Strange behaviour of a class destructor in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CCC {
public:
    CCC() {cout<<"created "<<++count<<endl;}
    ~CCC(){cout<<"deleted "<<--count<<endl;}
    int count=0;
};

CCC a;

CCC& create() { 
    return a; 
}

int main () {
    CCC result = create();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K3eR9t

The above code produces strange output. Looks like the destructor is called 2 times, but count is not decremented. Why is that?

```
created 1
deleted 0
deleted 0
```

Comment: FWIW: I highly recommend not returning a reference to a local variable in general. That's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `count` member is non-static, so each instance of `CCC` has its own copy.

For the instance `a`, the `count` member will be set to 0 when the default constructor starts, then incremented to 1 and printed. Later it will be destroyed, the `count` member decremented to 0, and printed again.

For the instance `result`, the `count` member is set to 1 by the copy constructor since it was 1 in `a`. When it is destroyed, the member is decremented to 0 and printed again.

If you wanted to track the total number of instances of the class that exist, you would need a static member,

```
static int count = 0;
```

Furthermore, you would need to increment it not only in the default constructor, but also in the copy and move constructors.

Answer (score 3):

In this statement

```
CCC result = create();
```

there was used the default copy constructor.

So the object result has the same value of the data member `count` as the global object `a`.

Then destructors for the both objects were called decreasing corresponding data members `count`.

It seems what you are trying to do is either the following

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CCC {
public:
    CCC() {cout<<"created "<<++count<<endl;}
    CCC( const CCC & ) {cout<<"created "<<++count<<endl;}
    ~CCC(){cout<<"deleted "<<--count<<endl;}
    int count = 0;
};

CCC a;

CCC& create() { 
    return a; 
}

int main () {
    CCC result = create();
}
```

and the program output is

```
created 1
created 1
deleted 0
deleted 0
```

or the following

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CCC {
public:
    CCC() {cout<<"created "<<++count<<endl;}
    CCC( const CCC & ) {cout<<"created "<<++count<<endl;}
    ~CCC(){cout<<"deleted "<<--count<<endl;}
    static int count;
};

int CCC::count = 0;

CCC a;

CCC& create() { 
    return a; 
}

int main () {
    CCC result = create();
}
```

In this case the program output is

```
created 1
created 2
deleted 1
deleted 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of constructor. You have instrumented the default constructor, but not the copy or move constructor. Please read up on the c++ rule of 3 / rule of 5 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the implicitly defined copy constructor.
It will copy the state of the other class by default, like:
`CCC(const CCC& other): count(other.count)`

For a full example see below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CCC {
public:
    CCC() {cout<<"created "<<++count<<endl;}
    CCC(const CCC& other): count(other.count) {cout<<"copied " << count << " others count " << other.count << endl;} 
    ~CCC(){cout<<"deleted "<<--count<<endl;}
    int count=0;
};

CCC a;

CCC& create() { 
    return a; 
}

int main () {
    CCC result = create();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YM36ax